# Utility to create a menu program that would not require an installer

Tags: menu, vbscript, hta

I would like to create a menu "program" so that when I give someone a DVD containing PDF files, mpg, mp3 files, etc., the user will be able to click on a menu's button or hyperlink to select the item s/he wants to open.

I tried using an .hta file, which works just fine on my computers.

My .hta file identifies the drive and folder where it is situated, and uses vbscript to identify the default executable which the client computer uses to open various extensions.
The .hta file uses the FileSystemObject to run the executable against the PDF or other file that the user selects.

Alas, several DVD recipients told me that their Windows computers did not recognize .hta files, i.e., they got various error messages, e.g., Windows wanted to know what program to use to open the .hta file.

Can someone recommend a simple open source approach to take, in lieu of an .hta file, which would not require the user to run an installer?

Comment: Why not just add an html file with links?

Comment: Security would interfere on some computers, though generally will work from harddrive. CD running I think is controlled by Tools - Internet Options - Advanced in IE. There are two settings under security (Active Content).

Comment: Dear Clayton, thanks for the suggestions.  But an HTML file with links doesn't work on some computers, for reasons which elude me.

Comment: Dear David:  Thank you for alerting me to that issue.  Maybe that is why the .hta file was not recognized.  I'll investigate.

Comment: @user235218 Notice, that HTAs are run by mshta.exe. Looks like it's not included in all versions of Windows8.